# Database Primary Key's -> An identity field AND a name field?

Tags: database-design, primary-key

all my tables have an `Id` field of some type (`UserId, PostId, FooId`, etc). I usually make this a *Primary Key*.

A table I have is called `Countries`. It has

```
CountryId SMALLINT
Name VARCHAR(100)  -- Yes, english country names only, in this column.
AndSomeOtherFields.
```

Now, I know the `Name` has to be unique. All country names are unique. Is it good/bad/ru-roh if i make the `PrimaryKey` == `CountryId ASC` *and* `Name ASC` ?

If it's good, can someone explain why it's better, than just the `Id` being the PK? Is it just that it ensures data integrity (eg. no two country names existing in the table). If it's bad .. why?

thanks kindly.

Comment: #Duplicate * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166750/should-i-have-a-dedicated-primary-key-field
* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695325/should-i-use-natural-identity-columns-without-guid And that's just the ones I could see on the right, this question has been asked quite a few times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Making the primary key both `CountryId` *and* `Name` does not ensure the names are unique. It just ensures that each `CountryId`-`Name` *pair* is unique, and obviously `CountryId` is already unique, being an "ID". So you could still have, for example, `1-US` and `19-US`, as the pairs are unique.

The only reason to make them both the primary key is if you will be frequently executing queries where both CountryId and Name are used in the Where clause. The primary key *by default* creates a clustered index, which physically sorts the table, so it makes lookups for rows against those predicates very fast.

Another important point to raise is that in your particular example, you are storing a list of countries which is a) very short and b) doesn't change much. Lookups against this table are going to be *extremely* fast no matter what you do. Even if SQL Server has to do a full table scan every time, you probably won't even notice. You don't have to worry about page fragmentation. You could just skip the ID column and use the `Name` as a primary key.

Or, if you want to keep an ID but also enforce uniqueness of just the country names, you can [put a Unique Constraint](http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/a/unique.htm) on the Name column.

It is difficult to cover the issue of primary keys, clustered indexes, and indexes in general, in too much depth in a single answer. Here are a few good resources to get started:

- [When should primary keys be used?](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/faq/primary_key_index_clustered_p1.aspx)
- [An Introduction to Clustered and Non-Clustered Index Data Structures](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/per/index_data_structures_p1.aspx)

Comment: "The primary key physically sorts the table" Not on my RDBMS it doesn't; that has to be done explicitly, and can be done for any index. Otherwise, this is solid advice.

Comment: @kquinn thanks, added that clarification. I meant that at the beginner level (which seems to be where we're at here) primary key automatically comes with a clustered index as well.

Comment: Thanks :) I should not have used a Countries table as my example because it's a small table. The question was sorta targetted against any size table. But i feel like it's been aswered none the less :)

Answer (score 1):

Having the name become the PK is not always the best solution, I believe CountryId is enough as a PK for your table, however if Name is a field which you will be using alot to query with ie: selects,joins ,  you should index this field this way a query filtering by this field will improve it's speed alot

good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a **unique index** on the column `Name`.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is pretty obvious: your index will be a little bigger. Having said so, it's not such big a deal since your table will be only storing countries. But, why would you like such an index? If you sort by **CountryId**, then sorting it by **Name** as second field is pointless. You will always get the same order.

One thing that is really a bad idea is to have foreign keys pointing to a large primary key, so, make sure that if you use that primary key, your foreign keys pointing to *Countries* still use only **CountryId** column.

Answer (score 0):

Country names have been known to change without otherwise altering the country's identity. That suggests that the name should not be part of the PK.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to enforce uniqueness, use a constraint.